# Hot to change theme at run-time in ASP.NET Core Angular application

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, sass

I would like to build ASP.NET Core Angular application and allow users to change theme at run-time.

I already tried with sass. In the build process I managed to build application several times (one time for each theme). My output is `dist_theme1`, `dist_theme2` ...
But I don't know how run application for each theme? (Before multiple approach I had this line, which I think served Angular app:)

```
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
    configuration.RootPath = "wwwroot/dist";
});
```

but how to tell IIS which Angular app should start. I checked how multiple Angular can be started by the same ASP.NET Core, but it requires the change of URL, which I want to avoid.

Second thing I found is to use css variables and change theme with javascript. This looked promising, but css are embedded in lazy loaded modules. Would that be a problem? It also requires that theme is styled in string ([example I found](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-themes-for-your-angular-7-apps-using-css-variables-69251690e9c5/)), but the biggest problem is that third party components I used doesn't support css variables, only plain css and sass.

Is there another option?
What is the recommended path/option to change theme at run-time and saved this to logged in user/local storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view this blog post [here](https://medium.com/atom-platform/angular-6-dynamic-themes-without-a-library-c21dfb2cb580)

The author explain to use scss in this case and simply inject scss variable at runtime.

Please let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Hi. This helped me, but not fixed my problem. I need to assign css variable into sass variable: `$primary: var(--primary-color);`. `Primary` is variable used by third party components and I get error in `sass-loader` for line `@return mix(rgba($primary, 1), rgba($secondary, 1), $weight); ` and I can not change this is code, because it is written by third party (Kendo UI for Angular).

Comment: can you override of that class element in your own code?

Comment: Maybe. I am not sure what you mean. I can say, that I have complete source code, but I do not want to change files inside node_modules. Anything else, I can do.

Comment: What I mean is you can override library css code with your own css

Comment: Yes I can override it, but there are to many classes to do that.

Comment: I get official answer that they will provide theme which will support CSS variable. Thanks for the ideas.